# C# Unity serializing nested object does not add sub object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to serialize a nested object, but when I use the IFromatter, the nested object gets added as "true" instead of the actual object.  I can see this in the debugger, but I am not sure what is causing it?  Here are my classes I am serializing:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Save Object", menuName = "Save Object")]
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveObject : ScriptableObject
{   
    public Inventory PlayerInventory;
    public string sceneName;
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Inventory", menuName = "Inventory/Inventory")]
[System.Serializable]
public class Inventory : ScriptableObject
{
    public Item currentItem;
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
    public int coins;
    public FloatValue PlayerHealth;
    public FloatValue PlayerMana;
    public FloatValue PlayerStrength;
    public FloatValue PlayerXP;
    public IntegerValue PlayerLevel;
    public FloatValue PlayerGold;
    public PlayerPosition PlayerPostion;

    public int NumberOfKeys()
    {
        //int numKeys = Items.Count(element => element.itemType == ItemType.key);
        /// return numKeys;
        return 0;
    }
    public void RemoveInventoryItem(Item item)
    {
        Items.Remove(item);
    }

    public void addCoins(int coin)
    {
        coins = coins + coin;
    }
    public void removeCoins(int coin)
    {
        coins = coins - coin;
    }
    public void AddHealth(int points)
    {
        if (PlayerHealth.RuntimeValue < PlayerHealth.MaxValue)
        {
            PlayerHealth.RuntimeValue += points;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerHealth.RuntimeValue = PlayerHealth.MaxValue;
        }
    }
    public void AddStamina(int points)
    {
        if (PlayerStrength.RuntimeValue < PlayerStrength.MaxValue)
        {
            PlayerStrength.RuntimeValue += points;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerStrength.RuntimeValue = PlayerStrength.MaxValue;
        }
    }
    public void AddMana(int points)
    {
        if (PlayerStrength.RuntimeValue < PlayerStrength.MaxValue)
        {
            PlayerStrength.RuntimeValue += points;
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerStrength.RuntimeValue = PlayerStrength.MaxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

My serialize class is this:

```
public class SavePlayer : Singleton<SavePlayer>
{
    public void SaveGameState(SaveObject playerSaveObject,string saveName, string sceneName)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Configure our surrogate selectors.
            var surrogateSelector = new SurrogateSelector();
            surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof(SaveObject), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All),
            new SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate());
            surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof(Inventory), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All),
           new InventorySerializationSurrogate());

            //Serialize the object
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.SurrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;      
            formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, playerSaveObject);
       
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            SaveObject deserializedPerson = (SaveObject)formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }

    }
    public void LoadGameState(string SavePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(SavePath))
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat("File does not exist {0}", SavePath);
        }
        IFormatter formatter = GetBinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(SavePath, FileMode.Open);
        try
        {            
            SaveObject saveObj = (SaveObject)formatter.Deserialize(file);    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Failed to load file at {0}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    public IFormatter GetBinaryFormatter()
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        SurrogateSelector surrogateSelector = new SurrogateSelector();

        SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate = new SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate();
        InventorySerializationSurrogate InventorySerializationSurrogate = new InventorySerializationSurrogate();

        surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof(SaveObject), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate);
        surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof(Inventory), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), InventorySerializationSurrogate);

        formatter.SurrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;
        return formatter;
    }
}
public class InventorySerializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Inventory inventory = (Inventory)obj;
        info.AddValue("coins", inventory.coins);
    }
    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        Inventory inventory = (Inventory)obj;
        inventory.coins = (int)info.GetValue("coins", typeof(int));
        return inventory;
    }
}    

public class SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        SaveObject saveObject = (SaveObject)obj;  
        info.AddValue("scene_name", saveObject.sceneName);
        info.AddValue("PlayerInventory", saveObject.PlayerInventory );  //<----This gets added as "True" instead of the object

    }
    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        SaveObject saveObject = (SaveObject)obj;    
        saveObject.sceneName = info.GetString("scene_name");
        saveObject.PlayerInventory = (Inventory)info.GetValue("PlayerInventory", typeof(Inventory));

        return saveObject;
    }
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
string scene_name = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
saveManager.SaveGameState(saveObject,name, scene_name);
```

In my SavePlayerObjectSerializationSurrogate method, at this line: `info.AddValue("PlayerInventory", saveObject.PlayerInventory );` I can see that the saveObject.PlayerInventory is an object, with all values, but after it is added to info, it is just added as "true".  This, then, means when I try to "deserialize" the object, my code is expecting an object of type Inventory, but receives a bool, causing an error.  Is it possible to add complex objects to be serialized?

thanks

Comment: Why not just converting to json instead of the surrogates and other in between actions?

Comment: Is there an added value to using json over IFormatter?  I am new to Unity, so I am using tutorials I find online.  I have not found one that uses json for serialization.

Comment: I also want to make sure the files are not human readable, to prevent tampering.

Comment: You can convert the json to binary or encrypt. Json would just make it more straightforward